# Assign Koalas Column from Numpy Result

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, databricks

Trying to replicate Pandas Functionality in Databricks-Koalas
In Pandas:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a': [450, 1, 26],
                   'b': [1, 450, 70],
                  })
thresh = [x for x in range(26)] # create a list 1 to 25
df["c"] = np.where((df.a.isin(thresh) | df.b.isin(thresh)), 1, 0) # find the values within the threshold and flag column 'c'
df
# returns
Out[32]: 
     a    b  c
0  450    1  1
1    1  450  1
2   26   70  0
```

In Koalas:

```
df = ks.DataFrame({'a': [450, 1, 26],
                   'b': [1, 450, 70],
                  })

thresh = [x for x in range(26)] # create a list 1 to 25
df = df.assign(c=np.where((df.a.isin(thresh) | df.b.isin(thresh)), 1, 0)) # find the values within the threshold and flag column 'c'
# returns
PandasNotImplementedError: The method `pd.Series.__iter__()` is not implemented. If you want to collect your data as an NumPy array, use 'to_numpy()' instead.
```

How do I properly use `to_numpy` as it is expecting or wrap the Numpy result in a ks.Series() so that the assign() will take the result?

`df = df.assign(c=ks.Series(np.where((df.a.isin(thresh) | df.b.isin(thresh)), 1, 0)))` gives the same error as above.

Is there a way to replicate the pandas functionality in the koalas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To perform the operation you do here in a `ks.DataFrame`, you don't need `np.where`, but you could use `astype`:

```
df = df.assign(c= (df.a.isin(thresh) | df.b.isin(thresh)).astype(int) )
df
     a    b  c
0  450    1  1
1    1  450  1
2   26   70  0
```